# How can I dynamically access all config parameters starting with 'var' defined in config/applications.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my config/applications.rb, I have set parameters:

```
config.var1 = 1
config.var2 = 5
config.varx = 7
```

I can access them using

```
Rails.application.config.var1
```

I am trying to dynamically build a hash of all config parameters with names starting with 'var', so the output would be

```
{var1: 1, var2: 5, varx: 7}
```

I have looked at the Rails.application.config.methods, Rails.application.config.instance_variables, Rails.application.config.inspect etc. and they don't return the var1 etc.

How can I dynamically access all config parameters starting with 'var' defined in config/applications.rb?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you create a hash in the first place and set it in the config?

Comment: In my experience, when someone asks "how do I get all variables named like this?", there's __always__ a better solution. Usually it involves creating iterable structure from the beginning.

Comment: Expanding on @SergioTulentsev: The problem is solved if you have `Rails.application.config.variables = {var1: 1, var2: 5, varx: 7}`. Then you can do `Rails.application.config.variables.select { |key| key.to_s.first(3) == 'var' }`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : The application has numerous parameters set in application.rb and many of them are overridden in environment configs. To move them now to a hash would require re-factoring with no business value. This exercise is to display a consolidated list within each environment at runtime.

Comment: @Anil: business and deadlines, yeah. May your next project turn out better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I completely agree with @SergioTulentsev that *you are doing it wrong*, you are still free to:

```
Rails::Railtie::Configuration.class_variable_get(:@@options)
                             .select { |k, _| k =~ /\Avar/ }
#⇒ {
#    :var1 => 42
# }
```

As a matter of fact, the access to this class variable is provided via [`method_missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe1f4b2ad56f010a4e9b93d547d63a15953d9dc2/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb#L89).

Comment: This clearly works, well done.

But yea... don't do this ;)

Comment: Good one. Did you know it was stored in `@@options` or have you somehow figured it out?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: it's open-source, you know :) And in ruby, it's open-source __at runtime__!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev right-right, I am just wondering whether [at]mudasobwa knew in advance or has searched right before answering :) Just curious :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko if you are interested in the investigation process, I passed the missing name to the `Rails.application.config.★`, and immediately saw that exception was thrown in `railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in \`method_missing'`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I know nothing in Rails in advance and I even do not have a rails badge here. Any time I dig into it’s code I find smth like ⇑ and it makes me sick :)

Comment: Yep, you even added it to the answer, didn't notice.

Comment: If I were to do it, this is how it'd look like, roughly https://monosnap.com/file/ImeAt2tuSETECZbgsX3vhyd5pLqrAH.png

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Man, that is a true voodoo magic! Do you have these fancy hinting arrows in your shell at any time you debug things?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev cool, never seen this `cd` trick before. TIL, thanks!

Comment: @mudasobwa: haha, nice one :)